# Why does Java complain about passing in a Collection<Enum> where you expect a Collection<Object>

Tags: java, enums

I have some code that just takes in a Collection and checks for null if it not just converts it all toString for you.

```
static Collection<String> test1(Collection<Object> objects) {
        if(objects != null) {
            return objects.stream().map(x -> x.toString()).collect(Collectors.toList())
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

It works fine if I do this

```
Collection<Object> myCollectionOfObjects = new ArrayList<>();
test1(myCollectionOfObjects);
```

but java complains if I pass in a collection of Enums

```
Collection<SomeEnumIHave> myCollectionOfEnums = new ArrayList<>();
test1(myCollectionOfEnums);
```

The exception I get is

`Error:(283, 87) java: incompatible types: java.util.Collection<SomeEnumIHave> cannot be converted to java.util.Collection<java.lang.Object>`

But from reading online, it seems that Enums are actual reference types, so it should be an Object.

I have multiple ways of working around this, but I'm confused why it's happening.

**Edit**
I should point out that any other object type works fine. So it's not an issue with generics (the method itself isn't generic anyway), it seems to be something like a boxing issue, but Enums shouldn't need to be boxed.

```
Collection<MyCustomObject> myCollectionOfObjects = new ArrayList<>();
test1(myCollectionOfObjects);
```

Comment: @JNL No, `enum` are just extra syntax for defining a `class` in a specific way. `enum` values are reference type values.

Comment: [It definitely does not work with other object types.](http://ideone.com/UNpC9B)

Comment: You are correct. @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Opps, I got confused in some of my code, I had generics on one part and not another. You are correct @SotiriosDelimanolis, was looking at the wrong code when I saw the "working" code